# What is the complexity of this code whose nested for loop repeatedly doubles its counter?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

In the book *Programming Interviews Exposed* it says that the complexity of the program below is O(N), but I don't understand how this is possible. Can someone explain why this is?

```
int var = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   for (int j = i+1; j < N; j *= 2) {
      var += var;
   }
}
```

Comment: *"It says"*  What says? Tell us whatever it is that you are assuming here.

Comment: I made the edit, sorry about the vagueness

Comment: This loop structure is very closely related to the one for the heapify algorithm and the analysis will be very similar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a bit of math to see that. The inner loop iterates `Θ(1 + log [N/(i+1)])` times (the `1 +` is necessary since for `i >= N/2`, `[N/(i+1)] = 1` and the logarithm is 0, yet the loop iterates once). `j` takes the values `(i+1)*2^k` until it is at least as large as `N`, and

```
(i+1)*2^k >= N <=> 2^k >= N/(i+1) <=> k >= log_2 (N/(i+1))
```

using mathematical division. So the update `j *= 2` is called `ceiling(log_2 (N/(i+1)))` times and the condition is checked `1 + ceiling(log_2 (N/(i+1)))` times. Thus we can write the total work

```
N-1                                   N
 ∑ (1 + log (N/(i+1)) = N + N*log N - ∑ log j
i=0                                  j=1
                      = N + N*log N - log N!
```

Now, [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) tells us

```
log N! = N*log N - N + O(log N)
```

so we find the total work done is indeed `O(N)`.

Comment: kudos for the ASCII equations / art

Answer (score 4):

Outer loop runs `n` times. Now it all depends on the inner loop.
The inner loop now is the tricky one.

Lets follow:

```
i=0 --> j=1             ---> log(n) iterations
...
...
i=(n/2)-1 --> j=n/2     ---> 1 iteration.
i=(n/2) -->   j=(n/2)+1 --->1 iteration.
```

---

```
i > (n/2)            ---> 1 iteration
(n/2)-1 >= i > (n/4) ---> 2 iterations
(n/4) >= i > (n/8)   ---> 3 iterations
(n/8) >= i > (n/16)  ---> 4 iterations   
(n/16) >= i > (n/32) ---> 5 iterations

(n/2)*1 + (n/4)*2 + (n/8)*3 + (n/16)*4 + ... + [n/(2^i)]*i

   N-1                                   
 n*∑ [i/(2^i)] =< 2*n
   i=0  

--> O(n)
```

Comment: Did you mean `j` instead of `i` in the second box?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, no. I meant `i`, when the outer loop is in these ranges, j will get assigned `1 2 3 4 5...` different values (number of iterations) BTW, nice reputation gain :). Few days ago you had 800~

Comment: But `j` is the variable that grows exponentially, not linearly like `i`? And I don't think that the number of iterations increases linearly like you have said.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog ofcourse j grows exponentially. When `i` is n/2, then j will be n/2+1 and then the loop will break. So j had only `1 value before the inner loop stopped` (ran one iteration).

Comment: No, the inner loop will not break when `i = n/2` (in fact, not until `i = N - 1`), because `j *= 2` happens *after* the first inner loop iteration - and only *then* will the inner loop break. And thanks :) I got lucky

Comment: @meowgoesthedog different terminology. When `i = n/2` do you agree inner loop will run only one time ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151535/discussion-between-tony-tannous-and-meowgoesthedog).

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Fischer's answer is correct.

I would like to add the fact that this algorithm's exact running time is as follows:

[image]

Which means:

[image]