# Complexity of the program

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have gone through random posts on algorithm and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286613/program-complexity) that the complexity of below code is **O(n)**

```
int var= 2;
for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
   for (int j=i+1 ; j<N ; j*=2) {
      var += var;
   }
}
```

There, the accepted answer describes the reason with mathematics. Actually, I did not understand the solution.

Can anyone help me to understand why the complexity is **O(n)** with the view of a programmer?

Comment: There is no way to explain this from *"the view of a programmer"*. This problem is purely mathematical and has no relation to programming

Comment: Read my answer there.